# What changed in Visual Studio 2017 regarding pipes and child processes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, createprocess

I've got a program that worked fine when compiled with Visual Studio 2010, but now that I'm using Visual Studio 2017 fgets/fputs don't seem to work correctly.
(Yea I know how that sounds and I'm sure the problem is me, **not** Visual Studio...)

It's a Visual Studio solution with 3 projects, all Visual C++ command line apps.

Program 1 launches Program 2 and Program 3, using pipes to send stdout of Program 2 to stdin of Program 3.
Thusly

```
lastPipe = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
/* Duplicate stdin to input_desc */
DuplicateHandle(thisProcessId, lastPipe, thisProcessId, &input_desc2, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

sa_first.nLength = sizeof(sa_first);
sa_first.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa_first.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
CreatePipe(&readPipe2, &out_desc2, &sa, 16384);

/* Duplicate the input_desc handle so it can be closed */
DuplicateHandle(thisProcessId, readPipe2, thisProcessId, &lastPipe, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
CloseHandle(readPipe2);

memset(&si2,0,sizeof(si2));
si2.cb = sizeof(si2);
si2.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si2.hStdInput = input_desc2;
si2.hStdOutput = out_desc2;
si2.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

CreateProcess(NULL, "program 2.exe", NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&si2,&pi2);

// Send Program 2 stdout to Program 3 stdin
DuplicateHandle(cpid, lastPipe, cpid, &input_desc3, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS));
CloseHandle(lastPipe);

out_desc3 = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

memset(&si3,0,sizeof(si3));
si3.cb = sizeof(si3);
si3.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si3.hStdInput = input_desc3;
si3.hStdOutput = out_desc3;
si3.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

CreateProcess(NULL, "program 3.exe", NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&si3,&pi3);
```

(Error checking removed for brevity)

Now for the juicy bit.  Program 2 has this:

```
// Program 2
fputs("Hello world", stdout);
putc('\n', stdout);
fputs("This should be line 2", stdout);
putc('\n', stdout);
```

Lastly, Program 3 has this:

```
// Program 3
char buffer[1024];
retval = fgets(buffer, 500, stdin);
fprintf(stderr, "|%s|", buffer);
```

When compiled with Visual Studio 2017, the output from Program 3 is

```
|Hello worldThis should be line 2\n|
```

(Note the lack of newline between "world" and "This", even though it's part of stdout from Program 2)

It does not happen every time, only after a few hundred (or thousand) calls to the fputs/putc functions.

This works without incident when compiled with Visual Studio 2010.

I've read (and re-read, and re-read again) the VS change log (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015), though nothing in there seems related to CreatePipe, CreateProcess, fputs/putc/fgets...

I also came across this:
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/502037/redirect-stdout-to-a-pipe-with-visual-studio-2015
Sadly, "I only use posix calls" wasn't as illuminating/explicit as I seem to need.

I've changed it to

```
fputs("Hello world\nThis should be line 2\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

And then

```
fputs("Hello world\r\nThis should be line 2\r\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Neither of which worked.

I tried opening a command prompt and doing

```
"Program 2" > temp.txt
"Program 3" < temp.txt
```

That does work, though it's not an acceptable solution (our users will not stand for such a thing)

What do I need to change to get this to behave as it did in VS 2010?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Suggestion: If no error `putc` returns the value written; if there is an error it returns `EOF`. You could test the return value and report the error number if it happens. see: return value here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c8e91sd.aspx

Comment: Well I'm more than a little embarrassed that it didn't occur to me to check the return codes, so it's with mixed emotions that I report it all seems to work.  That is, every call to puts/fputs/putc/etc returns the values one would expect if they were successful.  Also, after each call, ferror(stdout) returns false.
It seems "Program 2" thinks all its writes are successful. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your project settings, in particular the debug page and make sure that the command line and working directory are set as you expect. That page is all user settings (meaning they won't move with a project).

I'm not even sure that VS will import that page if you were to open the solution from the same directory in an updated version of VS (say a vs2010 project in vs2017).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I went through each and every property on the "Properties page" (both project settings and user settings).  Except the properties in 2017 that did not exist in 2010, all are the same.